# WIQL - query External Link type

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, wiql

i am trying to query all work items with a link to pull request.
I cant find any [External Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops#external-link-types) operation except count .
In gui there is no such option .
[image]
Can i use WIQL to create a query to get all work items with pull request ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this time, it is not supported to query external links by WIQL. WIQL can only query work links.

Comment: any other way to get list of workitems with attached pull request ?